# Ruby version >= 1.9.2 error but using ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I encountered the following error whilst running `bundle install` with `ruby-debug19` in my Gemfile:

```
Installing linecache19 (0.5.12) /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:163:in `install': linecache19 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2. (Gem::InstallError)
```

So I upgraded to ruby 1.9.3 and when I run `ruby -v` I get:

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
```

However, running bundle install returns the same error again - how can this happen?

**UPDATE**
Okay, so even weirder:

I tried to run a rails command and it said rails is not installed on this system. I ran `sudo gem install rails` and saw it install. Then I ran `rails -v` again and its still saying its not installed! Anybody have any idea whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Seems bundle install is using Ruby 1.8.7

Use RVM to manage between different ruby version

Answer (score 1):

Did you reinstall `bundler` for Ruby 1.9.3? If not, `bundle` is still using the old version of Ruby.